# can't get grunt-contrib less to import properly

Tags: less, gruntjs

I have the following less

```
.signature-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  **.opacity(.6);**
}
```

and the following in my grunt file...

```
less: {
  development: {
    options: {
  paths: ["default/less","default/less/bootstrap"]
    },
    files: {
      "css/less.css": ['less/*.less']
    }
  }
}
```

and opacity declared in default/less/bootstrap/mixins.less

```
.opacity(@opacity) {
  opacity: @opacity;
  // IE8 filter
  @opacity-ie: (@opacity * 100);
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity-ie})";
}
```

but when I run grunt I get...

```
Running "less:development" (less) task
>> NameError: .opacity is undefined in less/sigature.less on line 61, column 5:
>> 60     position: absolute;
>> 61     .opacity(.6);
>> 62   }
Warning: Error compiling less/signature.less Us
--force to continue.
```

Comment: have you included mixins.less?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you need to include mixins.less like this:

```
@import "bootstrap/mixins.less"; //I don't know you folder organizations

//..code...

.signature-overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  .opacity(.6);
}
```

Comment: This should already be done in the core.less which is a different less file. Does that mean instead of compiling all I should just compile core?

Comment: Exactly try to compile only core file @Jackie

Answer (score 1):

The previous answer put me down the right path. Instead of building all I needed to point at an individual Less file that contained the import. This appears to make it work.